# Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json ..." and "BaseConfig ..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: React app running on on Microsoft edge]

I open Terminal, on my react folder, i start react app with `npm start`, but the error always come on the browser.

> Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » D:\os\zenom\zenom-react\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » D:\OS\Zenom\zenom-react\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

Comment: This is a fresh react installation with create-react-app? Or some project that you configured react by yourself?

Comment: Nice spot @CherryDT

Answer (score 26):

You are running your project from an incorrect, non-canonically capitalized working directory path.

The canonical path is `D:\OS\Zenom\zenom-react` but your working directory is `D:\os\zenom\zenom-react` (note the lower-case letters).

The solution is to make sure your working directory is set to the canonical path (the same as displayed in Windows Explorer).

**PowerShell:**

```
PS D:\os\zenom\zenom-react> cd D:\OS\Zenom\zenom-react
PS D:\OS\Zenom\zenom-react> npm start
```

**bash:**

```
user@machine MINGW64 /d/os/zenom/zenom-react
$ cd /d/OS/Zenom/zenom-react

user@machine MINGW64 /d/OS/Zenom/zenom-react
$ npm start
```

Accessing files will still work using a different capitalization since Windows filesystems are usually<sup>1</sup> case-insensitive, but the module loader doesn't see paths as equivalent if they have different capitalization (and some OS path manipulation methods will cause the canonical path to be returned), hence the error.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/4186).

---

<sub>**1:** Can be [configured](https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/).</sub>

Comment: saved me a lot of hair you did.

Comment: Thanks!! I spent a lot of time looking for a solution and this one solves my problem. Some solutions suggest to change the folder names, :o

Comment: The daftness of case sensitive file systems strikes again.

Comment: Fixed my issue as well.
I opened the folder from the powershell using `code .` but for some reason, one of the folder in the directory was with small alphabet when I ran `pwd`. But in fact, that folder name start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

kindly use the following steps:

1. close the code editor.
2. go to the folder and  change the name to lowercase.
3. restart the code editor and run `npm start` again.

Answer (score 1):

Today I am facing the same issue with macbook pro, then I just remove the eslint config in `package.json` and fixed it:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a case-sensitive issues especially in windows
solution:

go to the file location /d/OS/ and change it to /d/os/

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack for this issue if it's fine for you, run the npm start command after you save the updates and for sure it wouldn't produce an error thereafter because you are not rendering screen at the code manipulation time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).